# Change Password and Install VLC player

Tags: installation, 13.04, passwd

I am the new user of Ubuntu. Recently I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my system. Actually I want to change my previous password with the new one. Secondly , I want to install VLC player through commands. 
Please help me to sort out these problems ?

Comment: Please ask only one question per "question".

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'I want to change my previous password with the new one'. Can you login into your system or you have been locked out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install VLC via terminal (the command prompt):

1. open up the dash by clicking on the top most icon, the one with the ubuntu logo, on the launcher. The launcher is the dock on the left side of the screen.
2. Search for `terminal` and click on it.
3. On the terminal, type `sudo apt-get install vlc` and press enter.
4. Enter your password and press enter.

For an introduction to Ubuntu, check out http://ubuntu-manual.org for a download-able pdf manual.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change your password in System Settings (search it in the dash) and select the Users settings.

To install VLC you can use Software Center or enter the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know your current password

1. Go to `System Settings`
2. Click on `User accounts`
3. Click on Unlock (top right), then type the current password
4. Select you Account on the left (if not already selected), the click on the "dots" next to "password"
5. Type your current password and the new one, click on `change`

and you're done

#### For installing vlc see the other answers